# How to fetch the filename of an image and rewrite the path removing the file extension(jpg,png, etc.) using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am able to partially do this with the htaccess code below, but as it turns out I also need to remove the image's file extension, such as .jpg, .png, etc. from the new url as well.

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysitee\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*\.(jpg|gif|png))$ http://mysitee.com/?attachment=$1
```

For example, one of the many images I have is:

```
http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg
```

And when I use the code my new URL is this:

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage.jpg
```

How can I make this so it doesn't also add the path before the image? I want it to look like this:

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage
```

Answer (score 0):

A little guesswork and I got it working!

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://thetechreader.com/?attachment=$1
```

I just moved the `\.(jpg|gif|png)` outside of the parenthesis, and it seems to work.

I will leave the question open though if you have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a .php file and name it index.php and use the following code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['attachment'])) {

    if($_GET['attachment'] != "") {
        //Remove any html symbols or tags
        $attach = trim($_GET['attachment']);
        $attach = strip_tags($attach);
        $attach = htmlspecialchars($attach);

        echo '<img src="http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/'. $attach .'.png">'
        echo '<img src="http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/'. $attach .'.jpg">'
        echo '<img src="http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/'. $attach .'.gif">'
    } else {
        // Code to execute when nothing was entered
    }


}
?>
```

**EDIT:** Remember to change mysitee.com to your domain.